# Measure time with 2 ropes

Tags: time

You are given two ropes that when lit burn in one hour. Which one of the following time periods CANNOT be measured with your ropes? a) 50 min b) 30 min c) 25 min d) 35 min.

I know 30 minutes is definitely possible as we could burn the rope at both ends.

Comment: @Oray seems like so, but the question here is a bit weird. Seems like a, c, d are all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that:

> **All of the times can be measured**

Here's why:

> Assuming you are allowed to cut the rope and set as many portions as you would like on fire, you can measure a time of $\dfrac{60}n$ by cutting the rope into pieces and making sure that there are $n$ points lit at any given time. With two ropes, any times that can be written as one factor of 60 or a sum of two factors will work.
>  For a): $\dfrac{60}2 + \dfrac{60}3 = 30 + 20 = 50$ minutes
>
>  For b): $\dfrac{60}2 = 30$ minutes or $\dfrac{60}4 + \dfrac{60}4 = 15 + 15 = 30$ minutes
>
>  For c): $\dfrac{60}{12} + \dfrac{60}3 = 5 + 20 = 25$ minutes
>
>  For d): $\dfrac{60}{12} + \dfrac{60}2 = 5 + 30 = 35$ minutes

Comment: assuming that the rope is uniform.

Comment: Even if it is not, whenever one section burns out you can just light another area. Cutting the rope and keeping the right amount of sections lit could be difficult, but it is mathematically possible.

Comment: How can you be sure that N points are lit at any given time, if you don't know the initial distribution of the rope burning rate ? Are you cutting the ropes as they are burning ?

Comment: Possibly yes to the latter question. You could cut the rope into enough pieces that needing to cut in again would be extremely unlikely, but it would always be possible.